# How to solve the "Expected server HTML to contain a matching <header> in <div>" error in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, render

I'm using Next.Js and many of the solutions that I have seen depends of the aplication entry point.

This error is shown when I refresh my web aplication.

```
return (
    <header className="header header--1" data-sticky="true" id="headerSticky">
        <div className="header__top">
            <div className="ps-container">
                <div className="header__left">
                    <Logo />
                </div>
                <div className="header__center">
                    <SearchHeader />
                </div>
                <div className="header__right">
                    <HeaderActions />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <NavigationDefault />
    </header>
);
```

Comment: Please provide some code so we can understand what you are referring to.

Comment: **I just added the code above**

Comment: That code is not enough to reproduce the issue. Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Thanks @juliomalves for the comment, i could solve the problem.
This article help me a lot [link](https://blog.hao.dev/render-client-side-only-component-in-next-js).
It was a problem with CSR and SSR.
Client-side code was different from server-side code.